# Why can't $f\circ g$ be formed as a composite function here, and why can $g\circ f$ be formed?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, solution-verification, function-and-relation-composition

> The functions $f$ and $g$ are defined by
> $$\begin{align}
> &f(x)=2\sqrt{1-e^{-x}}\quad x\in\mathbb{R},x\geqslant 0\\
> &g(x)=\ln(4-x^2)\quad x\in\mathbb{R},-2<x<2.
> \end{align}$$
> Explain why 
> (i) $f\circ g$ can't be formed as a composite function
> (ii) $g\circ f$ can be formed as a composite function.

This is the first time I've faced a question like this, so I'm not totally sure what the answer to  this is.

This is my attempt:

For $-2<x<2$, $g(x)$ varies between $-\infty$ and $\ln4$. However, to form the composite function $f\circ g$ we require
$$g(x)\in\mathbb{R},g(x)\geqslant 0$$
but this is not always the case here, since as explained before $g(x)$ can also take negative values. Hence we cannot form the composite function $f\circ g$.

On the other hand, for $x\geqslant0$ we know that $f(x)$ is always between $0$ and $2$, which fits with our requirement for us to be able to form $g\circ f$ as a composite function (ie the requirement that $-2<f<2$), hence we can indeed form $g\circ f$.

Is that right? I'm not completely sure that my reasoning is ironclad.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should note that $fg$ is the _product_ of $f$ and $g$; the composition is $f\circ g$ (which you get by typing `f\circ g`).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry about that, in all my textbooks it writes the composition without $\circ$, I'll change it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're right.

You just need to look at what the images of $f,g$ are. If any of the images of $f$ or $g$ aren't contained in the domain of the other their composition won't be well defined.

The image of $g$ is just $(-\infty, g(0)=\log(4)]$, and the image of $f$ is just $[0,2)$. So the image of $f$ is contained in the domain of $g$ (which is to say that $[0,2)\subset(-2,2)$) while the image of $g$ isn't contained on the domain of $f$ (because $-1\in (-\infty, \log(4)]$ but $-1\not\in[0,\infty)$) hence you can define $g\circ f$ but not $f\circ g$.

A short, intuitive answer is try to evaluate $(f\circ g)(-1)$. Since $g(-1)<0$ $f(g(-1))$ isn't well defined so $f\circ g$ can't be well defined, while since for every value $f(x)$ can take $g$ has an image for that value $g\circ f$ is.

Comment: Thank you for the extremely clear answer. Would I be correct in saying then that the domain of $g\circ f$ is $x\in[0,\infty)$ and the image of $g\circ f$ is $(-\infty, \ln4]$?

Comment: Yes! This can easily be seen since $g(x)=g(-x)$ so the image of $g$ will be the same when the domain is $(-2,2)$ or $[0,2)$.

Comment: Great, thanks so much! I'll wait a bit before accepting your answer in case someone else has something important to add.